# Flutter / Dart - the use of "resultTextFieldController.text = resultOfCalculation;"

Tags: flutter, dart, row

Flutter / Dart - I have a simple diabetic app but am new to programming, so struggling a lot, even after watching hours of Flutter youtube videos!  My app currently has 4 input fields on one row and the result of a calculation of input1 - input2 below it.  I would like to change this, so that the top row has Input / Input / Output (in similar boxes) and the second row has Input / Input / Output (in similar boxes).  The code for my current app is shown below after some help on Stackoverflow.  It has been suggested that I use the command "resultTextFieldController.text = resultOfCalculation;" to put the result in a text box, but my main issue is where to put that line as everywhere I have put it so far, the line gets underlined in red.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with a meal....';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num4controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";

  _calculate() {
    if (num1controller.text.isNotEmpty && num2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(num1controller.text) -
            double.parse(num2controller.text);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num1controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Target Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num2controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num3controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num4controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs 2',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                  'Difference between Target Level and Current Level: $result'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you draw over the image to show the result you are looking for.

Comment: Good idea louis joseph, thanks, yes just added the bottom image to show what the results should look like (ish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with a meal....';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
        numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR2C2controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Target Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs 2',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                  'Difference between Target Level and Current Level: $result'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output Image]

Add this line to the textfield widget to allow only numbers to be inputted in the text field.

```
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you louis joseph, that's ideal.  How do you do this so quickly? So after your comment, I did notice that although just the number keyboard comes up on the screen, you can actually type letters into the box which will never be needed, so to add the line you suggested of "inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]," would be great. But where would it go, would you need to repeat it for every input or just higher up in the code, so you can insert it once and then throughout the app numbers are only ever allowed?

Comment: Yes, you have to add it in every textfield widget. I have edited the code and added the input formatter in the textfield widget.

Comment: Thank you again louis joseph, that's ideal.  I notice that there is now an "import 'package:flutter/services.dart';" at the top, what is that for? Also, since the last change, it no longer allows decimal input, only output? But it now won't allow letters, which is great.

Comment: i forgot to add the 'package:flutter/services.dart';" it is used by input formatted. Change FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly to FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}')) to use decimal number. change the number in regex from 2 to desired length ie. ^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2} to ^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,X} for decimal number more than 2

Comment: Thank you again louis joseph, that has worked and changing the regex from 2 to 1 also worked as this number will only ever be to 1 decimal place. Thanks